# find a result from a .doc type that store in a varbinary(max) column

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, varbinary, .doc

i want to write a query with Full-Text-Search on a column with varbinary(max) type that stored a .doc/.docx(MS-Word) file.
my query must returns records that contain a word in stored file.

is this possible?

if yes,how?(please write an example)

if yes,can we write that for other language(e.g Arabic,Persian or a UniCode characters)?

thank you beforehand.

Comment: Have you thought of using Lucene for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is fulltext indexing, which has been greatly improved in SQL Server 2008.

For an introduction, I would recommend checking out these articles here:

- [SQL Server 2008 - Creating Full Text Catalog and Search](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/)
- [Understanding Full-Text Indexing in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/)
- [Fulltext-Indexing Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/full-text-indexing-workbench/)

Once you understand this and have created your own fulltext catalog, you should be able to search something like this:

```
SELECT ID, (other fields), DocumentColumn
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'Microsoft Word')
```

And yes, Fulltext indexing and searching does support lots of languages - check out the links I've sent you and the SQL Server 2008 Books Online for details!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2005 or later, yes, you just need the filters:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=60C92A37-719C-4077-B5C6-CAC34F4227CC&displaylang=en

If you have SQL Server 2000, doc files can be indexed, but not the newer Office 2007 format as far as I know (I've heard you may be able to borrow the IFilter by installing Word 2007 on the server).

Comment: thanks for your answer,
i have SQL Server 2008 and .doc file.
if possible, write an example.