# How can I check availability of certain string in the word file, stored in a table in SQL server DB?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Can anybody help me to get the logic as well as the sql script to resolve the below problem.

How can I check availability of certain string in the word file, stored in a table in SQL server DB? Suppose, in one table, several word document files are inserted in particular varbinary(max) datatype column(Each row has one word(.docx) file). I want to retrieve only those records in which stored word file has contained that supplied string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365918/find-a-result-from-a-doc-type-that-store-in-a-varbinarymax-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find a result from a .doc type that store in a varbinary(max) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365918/find-a-result-from-a-doc-type-that-store-in-a-varbinarymax-column)

Comment: Tanks a lot for the help. Now I could solve my issue.